# Web based Visualization tools pulling large data sets directly from hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, visualization, data-mining

I'm looking at **Web based Visualization tools pulling large data sets directly from hive**.

My use case is this -:
Say we have done some offline analysis,the results of which are stored as tables in a storage box (Hadoop) and can be queried via Hive. 
In these tables I have only the field I am interested in visualizing. Since I need to expose and to this visualization to multiple stakeholders I need this hosted on the web, possibly over one of our internal web server. At this point in time, the data should be securely connected and directly connect via Hive

My criteria is this -:

1. Cost of license(vs one time purchase)
2. Leraning curve & adaptablity
3. (Low priority, but important)Visualization formats suited to digital Advertising as a use-case, like funnels, Lift attribution etc.

I like Tableu, but its very expensive (upward of 10000 USD per year) - was looking at something good, but cheaper. I evaluated **Datameer** and it looks promising, have you used it for similar usecases and what were your experiences ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it yet, but perhaps something like Zeppelin ( http://zeppelin-project.org ) might be useful to look at.